# Opening a file with an app using a command line in apple script or an automator app

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator

I want to be able to double click to open a files type (HTML) in a particular app (SeaMonkey composer).

Double clicking the file opens SeaMonkey Browser, but I want it to open in Seamonkey Composer. The only way to do it is with the following command line

```
seamonkey -editor "filename.html"
```

So, how can I use apple script or automator to open my html files in composer ?

Comment: Select your HTML file in Finder and Right-click > Open With. Or File > Get Info, and permanently change the file association in the Open With section.

Comment: Thanks but as I stated, the file only open in Composer with the command line or by clinking shortcuts while in Seamonkey Browser

Comment: OK, think I understand—so it's a single app that runs as either browser or editor, depending how it's launched, yes? (Presumably not a native Mac app.) Suggest creating an AS applet as custom launcher, then associate all your .html files with that. See Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following script as Application in Script Editor:

```
on run filesList
    repeat with fileRef in filesList
        do shell script "seamonkey -editor " & quoted form of POSIX path of fileRef
    end repeat
end run
```

Select View > Show Bundle Contents and give it a custom bundle ID. You can then change the file association as above.

The above assumes the `seamonkey` command is itself just a launcher; if it's actually the full application (which may be the case as it's obviously not a native Mac app), the middle line'll need tweaked a bit:

```
do shell script "nohup seamonkey -editor " & quoted form of POSIX path of fileRef & " >/dev/null 2>&1"
```

That should allow the shell script to exit as soon as the `seamonkey` process is launched, leaving Seamonkey running until you quit it from its GUI.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we are really close, but it's not working I think because we are not saying to the script where is the seamonkey application, what do you think?

Comment: Also, this is where I saw that the command was (seamonkey -editor "file.html") http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/command-to-open-file-in-seamonkey-composer-723205/

Comment: Could well be. `do shell script` doesn't have access to your Bash profile or custom environment variables, so you may well need to write the full path to the `seamonkey` executable, not just its name. Typing `whereis seamonkey` in Terminal may tell you that path [depending on what mood the gods of bash are currently in], if you aren't sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AppleScript to do this, this simple script should do the job:

```
set filePath to ((path to documents folder) as text) & "filename.html"
tell application "Seamonkey Composer" to open filePath
```

I don't have the Seamonkey Composer app to test, but it works with BBEdit.
Note that the `open` command must have a full path to the file.

Comment: Thanks, but i want all hmtl files, no matter where they are, to open in composer, so the path changes each time.

Comment: Pepe:  Then @foo has already provided the solution on how to change the default app for "html" files.